# Find the relative position-in-DOM of two elements anywhere within an HTML document

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have some HTML that can contain `<span>`s with a specific class (let's call it `marker`). These spans can be anywhere in the document under a particular `<div>` - as direct children, or nested arbitrarily deeply in other nodes.

I then have a particular piece of text selected by the use (so I can use a [`window.getSelection()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) call to find the anchor node from `Selection.anchorNode`). What I want to find out, using Javascript, and jQuery as needed, is the *last* `marker` `<span>` to occur in the documents before that selection. For example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>Some text<span class="marker">Marker 1</span></span>
    </div>
    <div>
       <div>
          <span>Foo</span>
          <span>THIS IS THE SELECTION ANCHOR NODE</span>
       </div>
       <span class="marker">Marker 2</span>
  </div>
</div><!-- end of container -->
```

would find `Marker 1`, even though they are "cousins".

Is there a "standard" approach to determining the relative "linear" positions of an element in the DOM so I can decide if one element is "before" the other?

I am not concerned with the position on the page (x, y), so things like CSS `order` do not matter.

---

Things I have thought of, but seem suboptimal:

- traversing the parents of each `.marker` (and the selection span) using `[closest()][2]` and constructing some kind of lexicographic ordering of nodes, which seems expensive and error-prone
- traversing parents of `.markers` and storing lists of the spans found within

Both of these seem like they need a lot of book-keeping and manual DOM traversal for something that sounds like the DOM already knows (since the document has its specific order).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because shows lack of research.

Comment: What code are you using to get your divs. That would be relevant to this question as well.

Comment: Does this gets what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/p4bf6ceg/

Comment: @HanletEscaño that has no reference to the anchor node from the Selection object, so it would not depend on the selection at all? The node is a straight HTML element from `selection.anchorNode`, but can be easily jQuery'd with `$( anchor_node )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Node.prototype.compareDocumentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition) method to find out if an element is prior to an other one:

```js
const anchor = document.getElementById("anchor");
const markers = document.querySelectorAll(".marker"); // get all the markers in DOM order
const previous = [...markers].filter( // get only the markers before
  (elem) => anchor.compareDocumentPosition(elem) === Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING
).pop(); // get the last one
console.log( previous );
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>Some text<span class="marker">Marker 0</span></span>
      <span>Some text<span class="marker">Marker 1</span></span>
    </div>
    <div>
       <div>
          <span>Foo</span>
          <span id="anchor">THIS IS THE SELECTION ANCHOR NODE</span>
       </div>
       <span class="marker">Marker 2</span>
  </div>
</div><!-- end of container -->
```

Comment: Ack! There was a function for it along! Thank you! And a nicely formulated way to pull out the right one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this should get you there:

```
let xpath = '(//span[@class="marker"][not(.//preceding::*[contains(.,"SELECTION ANCHOR")])])[last()]',
result = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
console.log(result.textContent);
```

Comment: This will not work if the user has selected text that occurs more than once in the document.